# egrep matching patterns containing 3 repeated digits, not consecutive

Tags: regex, unix, command-line, grep

Use egrep to match lines containing 3 repeated digits, not necessarily consecutive,i.e "3 33", "55 5", "666" or "a6b6c6d". I have an initial thought.

I tried:

```
 egrep '1[^1]*1[^1]*1' test
```

This will recoginize stuff like 1abd1df31. 
However, I try not to enumerate all digit from 0 to 9. So how can I generalize this using back reference?

Thanks ahead!

NOTE that: there these three digit should be identical. ie. 3aa2aa1aa should not match.

Comment: At least 3, or exactly 3?

Comment: @Robin Exactly 3. Thanks Robin!

Comment: I guess `1212121`should match? (4 `1` but 3 `2`)

Comment: @Robin yes! exactly as u described I guess. I grab this exercise to practice using egrep.

Answer (score 0):

This works for simple cases:

```
egrep '^[^0-9]*([0-9])[^0-9]*\1[^0-9]*\1[^0-9]*$'
```

Explanation:

- `[^0-9]*` zero or more non-digits
- `([0-9])` one digit captured with parens
- `\1` back-reference to the captured digit
- `[^0-9]` zero or more none digits
- `^` and `$` beginning and end of line

Caveat programmor:

It matches `3 foo 3 bar 3` but fails for `3 4 3 baz 3`. In other words, no other digits are allowed in the line, just the 3 you're looking for.

Try this Perl one-liner to match the tricky cases with multiple digit types.

```
perl -ne '$i=$_;%a=();$a{$_}++for(split//,$i);for(0..9){if($a{$_}==3){print $i;last}}'
```

For each line `$i` it creates a hash `%a` addressed by each character of the line, storing occurrence counts. Then I check for digits with occurrence counts of 3, if any found, line `$i` is printed.

Comment: doesn't match `12233232`

Comment: Yes I know, I mentioned this fact in the answer. But it matches all the examples supplied by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
   /(?=.*?(\d))(?:(?:.*?\1){3})/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kG9oN3)

**EXPLANATION:**

```
(?=.*?(\d))(?:(?:.*?\1){3})

Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=.*?(\d))»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d)»
      Match a single digit 0..9 «\d»
Match the regular expression below «(?:(?:.*?\1){3})»
   Match the regular expression below «(?:.*?\1){3}»
      Exactly 3 times «{3}»
      Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
      Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1 «\1»
```

Comment: Does this match something like `12233233` or `a6b6c6w`?

Comment: @walls check the demo.

Comment: does the OP want the entire line to match, or just the portion continaing the start-end of the 3 times the number occurs?

Comment: No lookaround in egrep, fellows. Also this would match `1111`.

Comment: @Walls I think the op wants a match (true/false) of 3 repeated digits from start to end, exactly 3.

Comment: @Robin, true twice :)

Comment: @Robin The op can use `grep`  with `--perl-regexp`

Comment: With `grep` yes. With `egrep`, my version doesn't seem to support the  `-P` flag (but I've read some should)... I guess it kind of depends on whether the OP has a requirement on the tool.